# Allow bookmarking in single-page app using History API

Tags: javascript, node.js, single-page-application, html5-history

I designed a single-page app using History API, with Node.js on the server and without any particular framework on the client (except jQuery). It has several tabs, like a.com/b, a.com/c, a.com/d.

Everything works fine, except when I go to a.com/d directly (for example if I bookmark this page). I would like the tab "d" to be displayed.

I thought of 2 approachs:

- Do this on the server side: but because my tabs are divs that are hidden or shown in a static HTML file, this solution seems hard to implement. The server should send a different HTML file depending on the request, but given that I have only one index.html, I don't see how to do.
- Do this on the client side: parse the URL in Javascript and then display the right tab. I implemented this solution and it seemed to work, until I tried a.com/d?param=value. This was a case that I did not handle. So I can improve my regexp, but I am afraid that this is a bad practice, and that maybe there will always be one case I did not think of.

What do you think is the best, and how to do it correctly please?

Comment: Even without using any framework you can make your own vanilla js template then if you see a path activate that template.

Comment: Can you tell me more details please?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/livingston/9570969 here is a vanilla js template... look into the source code of Backbone.js and see how they figure out what route the server is currently on, then if a certain route is active then display the contents of that template (or just use javascript to change that div to hidden vs visible.